# C# BulkCopy different performance results

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, sqlbulkcopy

I am using C# SQLBulkCopy

```
SqlBulkCopyOptions sqlBulkCopyOptions = useStaging ? SqlBulkCopyOptions.KeepIdentity | SqlBulkCopyOptions.TableLock : SqlBulkCopyOptions.KeepIdentity;
```

When running the code in out QA environment it is performant - but as soon as it is PRD the performance goes down, Activity Monitor on the SQL DB Server picks up the `insert bulk` as an 'Expensive Query' and at times times out, but this happens intermittently.

I have taken a backup of the PRD database and restored it to the QA environment, I cannot replicate the issue, even with the exact same call that was made in the PRD environment. The query does not even come up as an Expensive Query.

Any idea as to what could be causing this different results?

Comment: are you using the table lock only when running it in a QA environment? (according to your sqlbulkcopyotions setup)

Comment: @PeterHenry - no. the useStaging field is false so its only using KeepIdentity

Comment: Is the target table used by other queries? Perhaps it's being blocked sometimes.

Comment: Using TableLock can actually be beneficial in reducing lock contention and minimise logging. Also, is the table being replicated in production?

Comment: One other thought, is the database under the full recovery mode in prod, vs simple in QA?

Comment: lastly, have you tried changing the batch size ?

Comment: @DanGuzman no, just using the tables to store the data

Comment: @PeterHenry the both environments has the recovery mode as Simple.

The batch size is about 56 rows

Comment: Batch size of 56 and how many actual rows? That is quite a small batch. And why not use Tablock? Bulk Copy is fast enough with Tablock that it shouldn't affect anything